# Remove some borders inside HTML table

Tags: html, css, border

I'm building a table in HTML and I'm quite surprised, because I have problem with a simple thing: I want to remove top-borders of some rows.
Here's codePen example:

http://codepen.io/Loreno/pen/PpNwPy?editors=1000

Some rows in the example have a class hideTopBorder. This class looks like this:

```
   .hideTopBorder {border-top: none;}
```

I'd expect the borders to just disappear, but they're still there. I also tried adding this class to cells inside the rows, but it still does not work.
It seems to be such a simple thing, but turned out to be pretty hard for me.

Comment: You're going to edit your plunker and it will no longer contain relevant code for your question. The question needs to include a [mcve].

Comment: #hideTopBorder{border-top:none;}

Comment: @LakshmanKambam why? # is for IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your desired effect, you need to apply it it to the `td` and remove the bottom border as well. Try this:

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.tg td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-yw4l {
  vertical-align: top
}

.width-25 {
  width: 25%;
}

.hideTopBorder td {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="report-div">
  <table class="tg">
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4">TEST DATA</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4">DESCRIPTION</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-yw4l" style="width: 50%;" colspan="2">Customer </td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l" style="width: 50%;" colspan="2">Analyze</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hideTopBorder">
      <td class="hideTopBorder tg-yw4l width-25">Name:</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder">Owner:</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hideTopBorder">
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder">contact:</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder">Type:</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hideTopBorder">
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder">Phone number:</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder">Model</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hideTopBorder">
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder">Mail</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder">Location</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hideTopBorder">
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder">Contact</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder">number:</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hideTopBorder">
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder">Site</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder">board:</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l width-25 hideTopBorder"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4">SOMETHING</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution

Comment: @Loreno No problem! Glad it helps! :)